# ImportError: No module named 'schedule' when i using system to run a service

Tags: python, systemd

I  have written a script called `coinview.py` and it can run on **linux**. When I trying to run it as `systemd`, it raises error

`error:ImportError: No module named 'schedule'.`

I use `pip3` show schedule, it already exist. So i have no idea what's wrong with my script.

I print sys.executable and sys.path in systemd.

```
[Unit]
Description=coinview deamon
After=rc-local.service

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
Group=root
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/source/quotation_api
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 coinview.py
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```
ubuntu@ip-100-00-40-02:/etc/systemd/system$ pip3 show schedule
Name: schedule
Version: 0.6.0
Summary: Job scheduling for humans.
Home-page: https://github.com/dbader/schedule
Author: Daniel Bader
Author-email: mail@dbader.org
License: MIT
Location: /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```

```
Mar 27 08:40:10 ip-100-00-40-02 python3[8634]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Mar 27 08:40:10 ip-100-00-40-02 python3[8634]:   File "coinview.py", line 3, in <module>
Mar 27 08:40:10 ip-100-00-40-02 python3[8634]:     import requests,threading,time,schedule,json
Mar 27 08:40:10 ip-100-00-40-02 python3[8634]: ImportError: No module named 'schedule'
Mar 27 08:40:10 ip-100-00-40-02 systemd[1]: coinview.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 27 08:40:10 ip-100-00-40-02 systemd[1]: coinview.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 27 08:40:10 ip-100-00-40-02 systemd[1]: coinview.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 27 08:40:10 ip-100-00-40-02 systemd[1]: coinview.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Mar 27 08:40:10 ip-100-00-40-02 systemd[1]: Stopped coinview deamon.
```

```
Apr 09 07:59:03 ip-100-00-40-02 python[12095]: /usr/bin/python3
Apr 09 07:59:03 ip-100-00-40-02 python[12095]:  ['/home/ubuntu/source/quotation_api', '/usr/lib/python35.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.5', '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x8
```

Comment: Have you tried `pip install schedule` on the command line?

Comment: Can you show what `sys.path` has? Try raising a dummy exception with it's value just to show it in the service startup log.

Comment: Sure, result is Requirement already satisfied.

Comment: `systemd` probably uses the system-side `python` to run the script. You can test this by running something like `import sys; print(sys.executable)` at the top of the script, and saving the output produced by `systemd`

Comment: In the same vein, you can add `#!/usr/bin/python3` at the top of the file to suggest to any process that just tries to run the file as an executable that it should use python3 to run it. That shebang should point to the python interpreter that has the `schedule` module installed to its side-packages, which is probably the `python3` at `/usr/bin`, but who knows.

Comment: >>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python35.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.5', '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']

Comment: @OrzHan it is highly important that you print the `sys.path` from the service not from a manual shell. The reason is because I'm guessing your environment in the service might be different than the one you expect.

Comment: @Arne  print(sys.executable) is /usr/bin/python , and i add #!/usr/bin/python3 at the top of my file, but it doesn't work

Comment: @andreihondrari  i print  sys.path as systemd,   ['/home/ubuntu/source/quotation_api', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/di

Comment: @OrzHan well obviously that in the systemd you are using `python2.7` which probably doesn't have the `schedule` package installed.

Comment: @andreihondrari  Oh, but how can i change it?

Comment: My script have been written ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 coinview.py, but systemd still execute my file with python2.7,why?

Comment: Tangentially, check the correct spelling of _daemon._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to these logs, i found that the PYTHONPATH is different in manual shell and systemd.And i try to add "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages" into /etc/profile  but systemd logs show that it still can't found the path.

So i do a stuip thing, add

```
sys.path.append("/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages")
```

in my code, and it works...

Answer (score 1):

Install the package for root with

```
sudo pip install schedule
```

Or instead of running it as root, try running it as another specific user.
Modify your .service to something like:

```
[Unit]
Description=coinview deamon
After=rc-local.service

[Service]
Type=simple
User=user
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/source/quotation_api
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 coinview.py
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I hope you used a specific username and not literally "User=user" .If so, is it the same error or different?

Comment: Maybe if you change it to `ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/python3.5 coinview.py`?

Comment: just installed the package with root solved my problem. Thanks, mate

Answer (score 0):

```
#importing the required libraries
import schedule
import time
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector as mysql
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime
```

Error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[19], line 2
      1 # importing the required libraries
----> 2 import schedule
      3 import time
      4 import pandas as pd

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'schedule'
```

Answer (score 0):

pip install schedule  OR

pip3 install schedule

#3 is the version of the pip(Python Package Manager)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).