# Python in Linux: "ImportError: No module named X", but library exists

Tags: python, linux

I've recently updated a python script of mine on my server after installing Selenium. Whenever I try to execute the script: I get `"ImportError Module: No module named schedule"`, even tho it is installed:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: schedule in ./JET/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.1.0)
```

It happens with every library, and every library is installed.

I don't want to place the package in the same folder as the script, it raises even more errors.

I execute the script via another shell script, but it never gave me this error before.

My guessings are it has to do with PATH, but I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Sorry for not writing this as a comment, but I cannot comment yet.)

Hi, I wonder if that could be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55587418/importerror-no-module-named-schedule-when-i-using-system-to-run-a-service) or [this another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73260371/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-schedule).

I wonder if adding path before the import might help

```py
import sys 
sys.path.append("./JET/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages")
import schedule
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked! I saw the other two questions, but I couldn't figure out how to do it. Thank you!